# Wordpress Custom Menu Walker for WP V6+

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to do two things with a custom menu walker in wordpress v6+ due to the way the original HTML is structured

1. add an `<div>` element inside of each `<a>` item in my wordpress menu
2. add a class name to my `<a>` element

I tried in my site-nav.php

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'walker' => new custom_walker,
));
```

and in my functions.php

```
class custom_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        $output .=
        '<div class="nav-underline">';
        parent::start_lvl($output, $depth, $args);
    }

    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        parent::end_lvl($output, $depth, $args);
        $output .= '</div>';
    }

}
```

This doesn't seem to work, and I'm not even sure if this will put the additional element where I want. I want it to go here like this:

```
<ul class="nav-list">
  <li class="list-item">
      <a class="nav-item-a" href="#">item
      <div class="nav-underline"</div></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Let me know if you know how to create a wordpress menu walker like this?

Comment: Do you want to use custom menu walker for a specific reason? Another solution would be to use `wp_get_nav_menu_items` function to create your own html structure. It is much easier to understand and to use.

Comment: I would like to create m own HTML structure, yes definitely. Do you have a solid example of that, which is easy to follow?

Answer (score 1):

You do not necessarily need to modify the `start_lvl()` and `end_lvl()` methods of the custom walker class

To achieve the desired result, you should modify the `start_el` method to add the required elements:

```
public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = null, $id = 0 ) {

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );

    $output .= '<li id="menu-item-' . $item->ID . '" class="' . $class_names . '">';

    $attributes = '';

    if ( ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ) {
        $attributes .= ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) . '"';
    }
    if ( ! empty( $item->target ) ) {
        $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target ) . '"';
    }
    if ( ! empty( $item->xfn ) ) {
        $attributes .= ' rel="' . esc_attr( $item->xfn ) . '"';
    }
    if ( ! empty( $item->url ) ) {
        $attributes .= ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) . '"';
    }

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a class="nav-item-a ' . implode( ' ', $item->classes ) . '" ' . $attributes . '>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '<div class="nav-underline"></div></a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );

}
```

Then, you can use the custom walker function with class:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'walker' => new custom_walker(),
    'menu_class' => 'nav-list',
));
```

Such a structure would be in HTML:

```
<ul class="nav-list">
  <li class="list-item">
      <a class="nav-item-a" href="#">item
      <div class="nav-underline"</div></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```